# R plumber api and data sending through Curl in windows

Tags: r, csv, curl, plumber

I need to send a CSV file using Curl in Windows to an R program using the `plumber` API. I have Curl installed in Windows.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work. I'm new to R and APIs, sorry.

The Curl command on Windows:

```
curl -X GET -d '@C:\Users\hp\Document\Final_Training.csv'
       http://localhost:8000/data1
```

gives the error:

```
"error":["500 - Internal server error"],"message":["Error in is.data.frame(x):
argument \"data1\" is missing, with no default\n"]}
```

My R `plumber` code is:

```
#* @get /data1
function(data1) {
  write.csv(data1, file="Final_Test.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, 
            col.names=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: This question is close to being reopened.  It might help if you explain how it "doesn't work".  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, i get this in command prompt,                                                              
curl -X GET -d '@C:\Users\hp\Document\Final_Training.csv' http://localhost:8000/data1
{"error":["500 - Internal server error"],"message":["Error in is.data.frame(x): argument \"data1\" is missing, with no default\n"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.  First, when "form data" is sent over HTTP, it's sent as a sequence of key/value pairs.  In particular, in a GET request, it's actually embedded in the URL.  For example, in the URL:

```
https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/?fg=1&utm_source=google.com&...
```

the key/value pairs are `fg=1`, `utm_source=google.com`, etc.

When you write Plumber code, the functions take arguments that correspond to the keys, so if Google was going to decide to deploy Plumber for their "About" page, they might write:

```
#* @get /intl/en/about
function(fg, utm_source, etc) {
    ...
}
```

In your code, you have Plumber code for URL `/data1` that also expects a `data1` key containing the CSV contents:

```
#* @get /data1         <-- the URL
function(data1) {      <-- which expects a `?data1=...` query parameter
  write.csv(data1, file="Final_Test.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, 
            col.names=TRUE)
}
```

To get Curl to do this (provide the data from a file using a key `data1` and supply it encoded in the URL for a GET request), you need to use a slightly different command line than you're using:

```
curl -X GET --data-urlencode 'data1@C:\Users\hp\Document\Final_Training.csv'
       http://localhost:8000/data1
```

That should get the data actually sent to the Plumber process.  On the Windows side, you should see an empty Javascript object `{}` response (so no error). On the R side, you'll see some weird warnings about attempts to set `col.names` and `sep` being ignored or something.  In addition, what gets written to `Final_Test.csv` won't be a proper CSV file.

That leads to the second issue.  In your plumber code, `data1` will be received as a plain character string containing the contents of the CSV file.  It will **not** be a data frame or anything like that.  If you just want to write the uploaded file to a CSV file, you'd just write the string `data1` to the file directly:

```
function(data1) {
    cat(data1, file="Final_Test.csv")
}
```

If you want to load it into a data frame, you'd want to parse the string as a CSV file using something like:

```
#* @get /data1
function(data1) {
    t <- textConnection(data1)
    X <- read.csv(t)
    close(t)
    print(summary(X))
    list(result=jsonlite::unbox("success"))
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply! When i do what you said, i get this following error in cmd.    Warning: Couldn't read data from file
Warning: "'data1@C:/Users/hp/Document/Final_Training.csv'", this makes an
Warning: empty POST.
{"error":["500 - Internal server error"],"message":["Error in textConnection(data1): argument \"data1\" is missing, with no default\n"]}